# Get values from array of objects, inside an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs, object

So, let's say I have this object, and inside of it, I have an array of objects.

```
let partys = {
    "id": 241,
    "name": "Rock Party",
    "type": "party",
    "days": [
        {
            "id": 201,
            "day": "Monday"
        },
        {
            "id": 202,
            "dia": "Friday"
        }
    ],
}
```

How do I get only the value of "day"? Like this:

`let days = ["Monday", "Friday"]`

I've already use Object.values(party.days[0]), but the result is:

`[201, 'Monday']`

Comment: You have two objects, one with a `day` property and one with a `dia` property. If that's a typo, then you can get the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array

Answer (score 0):

```js
let partys = {
    "id": 241,
    "name": "Rock Party",
    "type": "party",
    "days": [
        {
            "id": 201,
            "day": "Monday"
        },
        {
            "id": 202,
            "dia": "Friday"
        }
    ],
};

let days = partys.days.map(x => x.dia || x.day);
console.log(days);
```

This is the code which works with your data. But really I am sure that the name of the property should be `day` or `dia`, not both at the same time.

Comment: what if there is an object `{ id: 202, dia: 0 }`. Then this won't work

Comment: Sorry about that, I forget to translate to english the "dia" word. Both should be "day".

Comment: Buat that works fine! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `dia` is a typo:

```
const days = [];
for (let p of partys.days) {
  days.push(p.day);
}
console.log(days)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can easily achieve the result using [Nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)

```
partys.days.map((x) => x.dia ?? x.day);
```

```js
let partys = {
  id: 241,
  name: "Rock Party",
  type: "party",
  days: [
    {
      id: 201,
      day: "Monday",
    },
    {
      id: 202,
      dia: "Friday",
    },
  ],
};

let days = partys.days.map((x) => x.dia ?? x.day);
console.log(days);
```

Comment: That works too! Thank you!